# i am getting data from mssql in xml format and don,t know how to use in dhtmlxgantt

Tags: dhtmlx, gantt-chart

i am getting data from mssql in xml format that is

```html
<data><task id="1"><start_date>1906-10-04 00:00</start_date><duration>58</duration><text>Project #1</text><progress>0.6</progress><sortorder>0</sortorder><parent>0</parent></task><task id="2"><start_date>1906-10-05 00:00</start_date><duration>44</duration><text>fff</text><progress>0.7</progress><sortorder>1</sortorder><parent>1</parent></task><coll_options for="links"><item source="2" target="2" type="1"/><item source="3" target="2" type="1"/></coll_options></data>
```

and don,t know how to use in dhtmlxgantt so please if anyone can tell me how to do it my gantt,html code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body{
        margin:10px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }   
</style>
<head>
   <title>How to Start with dhtmlxGantt</title>
   <script src="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>   
   <link href="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gantt_here" style='width:1000px; height:400px;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 var tasks = {
    data:[
        {id:1, text:"Project #1",start_date:"01-04-2013", duration:11,
        progress: 0.6, open: true},
        {id:2, text:"DEEPAK",   start_date:"03-04-2013", duration:5, 
        progress: 1,   open: true, parent:1},
        {id:3, text:"Task #2",   start_date:"02-04-2013", duration:7, 
        progress: 0.5, open: true, parent:1},
        {id:4, text:"Task #2.1", start_date:"03-04-2013", duration:2, 
        progress: 1,   open: true, parent:3},
        {id:5, text:"Task #2.2", start_date:"04-04-2013", duration:3, 
        progress: 0.8, open: true, parent:3},
        {id:6, text:"Task #2.3", start_date:"05-04-2013", duration:4, 
        progress: 0.2, open: true, parent:3}
    ],
    links:[
        {id:1, source:1, target:2, type:"1"},
        {id:2, source:1, target:3, type:"1"},
        {id:3, source:3, target:4, type:"1"},
        {id:4, source:4, target:5, type:"0"},
        {id:5, source:5, target:6, type:"0"}
    ]
};
     gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"; 

 gantt.init("gantt_here");   
    gantt.parse(tasks);
           
   
  var dp=new dataProcessor("data.php"); 

 dp.init(gantt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the html code i am entering for dhtmlxgantt if any one can tell me how to use this data in dhtmlxgantt. it will be very helpful. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this dhtmlxgantt api (https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_xml_other.html) ? I believe this api will allow you to parse/serialize data in xml format.